# EJB class dependency between two EARs and third party jar library

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am fairly new to the whole Java EE EJB concept. I have done my research on EJB but yet to find a solution for my question.

Case Scenario:

I have remote EJB 1 on EAR 1 and remote EJB 2 on EAR 2 where EJB 2 has a reference to a third party library (XXX.jar). The method in EJB1 will be calling the method in EJB2 thru its bean interface which send the input to the method in the third party library for further processing. The result will feed back to EJB1 by heading the other way around via EJB1 remote method.

My question is when I add the class library (EJB2.jar) that contains the remote interface of EJB2 to the classpath of EJB2 project. EJB1 project will also contain the third party jar since it's in EJB2.jar. How can I avoid this? The third party jar should only be added to EJB2 project classpath.

Comment: J2EE was upgraded to Java EE almost 7 years ago. Are you really working with legacy J2EE? What version exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you have everything packaged but you shouldn't package the third party library/class with the EJB 2 client jar.  So from the little information I would assume you have:

```
EAR 1
|_lib
|   |_EJB2Client.jar
|
|_EJB1.jar

EAR 2
|_lib
|   |_Thirdparty.jar
|   |_EJB1Client.jar
|
|_EJB2.jar
```

So I dont think you have a problem where EAR1/EJB1 will have a reference to that third party jar.  If I understood your question correctly.  What does sound fishy is possibly how you have everything packaged.  If you require Remote EJB you should put all the client classes in an EJB-Client jar.  Also keep in mind you do not need to use Remote EJB if you are running in the same JVM.